# R data frame: Transform absolute date into day 1 for multiple factors

Tags: r, date, plyr, apply, posixct

I have a data frame which is organized as follows:

```
Subject ID  |      Collected Date        | Value  
3933332            9/14/2004 9:38           0.576
3933332            9/15/2004 3:48           1.164
3933332            9/17/2004 9:38           2.112
3933332            9/21/2004 1:00           1.547
6955455            5/12/2011 2:11           0.012
6955455            5/13/2011 1:31           0.023
6955455            5/14/2011 3:11           0.112
6955455            5/17/2011 12:11          0.342
...                ....                     ...
```

What I need is:

```
Subject ID  |      Day                   | Value  
3933332            1                        0.576
3933332            2                        1.164
3933332            4                        2.112
3933332            8                        1.547
6955455            1                        0.012
6955455            2                        0.023
6955455            3                        0.112
6955455            6                        0.342
...                ....                     ...
```

edit: for clarification, the new subject ID has a new start date.

I know that I can use as.Date to format the date (time is not relevant for me).
Next step would probably be to use a plyr and/or apply function to split up the set by subject ID, but I don't know how to do that.

Can you help me?

Comment: What is going to be different between the dates that lets you know to start the count again? Is the month? The year? Both? Something else?

Comment: @n8sty New subject ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one idea. I am not sure how exactly your data was composed. I, therefore, decided
to create a data frame based on what you have above. Please note that `Date` is `character` in `foo`.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(group_by(foo, ID),
       Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
       nDay = as.character(Date - Date[1] + 1))

#       ID       Date value nDay
#1 3933332 2004-09-14 0.576    1
#2 3933332 2004-09-15 1.164    2
#3 3933332 2004-09-17 2.112    4
#4 3933332 2004-09-21 1.547    8
#5 6955455 2011-05-12 0.012    1
#6 6955455 2011-05-13 0.023    2
#7 6955455 2011-05-14 0.112    3
#8 6955455 2011-05-17 0.342    6
```

Extra: This is my naive translation of the code above to a data.table idea.

```
DT = setDT(foo)[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")] 
DT[, nDay := as.character(Date - Date[1] + 1), by = ID]
```

**DATA**

```
foo <- structure(list(ID = c(3933332, 3933332, 3933332, 3933332, 6955455, 
6955455, 6955455, 6955455), Date = c("9/14/2004 9:38", "9/15/2004 3:48", 
"9/17/2004 9:38", "9/21/2004 1:00", "5/12/2011 2:11", "5/13/2011 1:31", 
"5/14/2011 3:11", "5/17/2011 12:11"), value = c(0.576, 1.164, 
2.112, 1.547, 0.012, 0.023, 0.112, 0.342)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's your estimate of the probability that the questioner's dataframe is actually composed of that same datatypes?

Comment: @BondedDust Thank you very much for your comment. It is hard to know how the original data is exactly composed unless we have `dput`. Here, my idea was to create a data by typing the numbers by hand so that I could support the OP. If you have any ideas for revision, please let me know. I am happy to work on it. :-)

Comment: Sorry if you took my comment as a criticism of the potential value of the code in the proper circumstances. It's just that I thought the datetime value was more likely to be a factor even if the questioner had figure out how to get headers edited and the separator issues resolved.

Comment: @BondedDust Ah, that is definitely a possibility. I will add that story in my suggestion. It is always better to prepare for some potential possibilities. :-)